# QuickTime Player > Export Clips

Tags: quicktime, mp4

I've got an mp4 in QuickTime which has been split into several clips.

How do I export these separately as audio tracks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File Menu > Duplicate [Cmd/Shift/s]
Delete extra clips.
File Menu > Export > Audio Only...  will save as .m4a

Repeat for each clip.

Tedious, but the best I can figure...

Comment: That exports the entire mp4. It doesn't export the separate clips.

Comment: Changed answer to include splitting out each clip.

Comment: Tedious but does the job.

Comment: I would say this is 'almost' optimal. My solution involves a little bit more nuance than trimming each one after copying. If you split and then cut the split clips over to a new file, you don't have to redo everything every time. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/340226/160704